# Pig distinct values in tuples

Tags: apache-pig

For example I have these fields in my tuples in A
A = (12,13)
(13,12)
(16,17)
(17,16)

now how can I remove the duplicate where (12,13) = (13,12) so my A =
(12,13)
(16,17)

Thank you so much
Onsiri

Comment: So you want to consider tuples (X,Y) and (Y,X) equal? Or why is then (17,16) removed from A?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should do something like the following:

```
A = <original dataset>;
SPLIT A INTO B IF $0 > $1, C OTHERWISE;
D = FOREACH B GENERATE $1, $0;
E = UNION C, D;
F = DISTINCT E;
```

Or, you could do this instead:

```
A = <original dataset>;
B = FOREACH A 
    GENERATE 
       CASE WHEN $0 > 1 THEN $1 ELSE $0 END, 
       CASE WHEN $0 > 1 THEN $0 ELSE $1 END;
F = DISTINCT B;
```

Note: It doesn't really scale well with more than 2 values in a tuple.